# Create Multimedia component with Metadata fields.using core service

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am creating Multimedia components using core service and everything is working fine. But when Metadata schema fields are defined on the Multimedia schema using which I am creating my Multimedia components then I am getting following error:-

Unable to find http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/DefaultMultimediaSchema:Metadata.

This message is displayed when I have given Default Multimedia schema's TCM ID for Multimedia component. As metadata fields are saved in Tridion Database so I first have to retrieve these fields from broker or what is the best solution for this, please suggest. Below is the sample code. Please modify it if someone have any idea for providing default value for metadatafields and how to retrieve them (with/without querying broker DB):-

```
 public static string UploadMultiMediaComponent(string folderUri, string title, string schemaID)
    {
        core_service.ServiceReference1.SessionAwareCoreService2010Client client = new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client(); 
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName"; 
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword"; client.Open();

        ComponentData multimediaComponent = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(
                                             ItemType.Component, folderUri);
        multimediaComponent.Title = title;

        multimediaComponent.ComponentType = ComponentType.Multimedia;
        multimediaComponent.Schema.IdRef =schemaID;

        //multimediaComponent.Metadata = "";

        StreamUpload2010Client streamClient = new StreamUpload2010Client();

        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(@"\My Documents\images.jpg",
                                                  FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        string tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent("images.jpg",
                                                               objfilestream);

        BinaryContentData binaryContent = new BinaryContentData();
        binaryContent.UploadFromFile = tempLocation;
        binaryContent.Filename = "images.jpg";
        binaryContent.MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData()
        {
            // for jpg file
            IdRef = "tcm:0-2-65544"
        };
        multimediaComponent.BinaryContent = binaryContent;

        IdentifiableObjectData savedComponent = client.Save(multimediaComponent,
                                                            new ReadOptions());

        client.CheckIn(savedComponent.Id, null);
        streamClient.Close();
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(savedComponent.Id);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Which version of tridion are you using? Also is the problem regarding metadata resolved?

Comment: Huston, I am using SDL Tridion 2011 GA. I don't get what do you meant by problem regarding Metadata as only about quering or providing value of Meatadata fields is the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code not working but following code is working for me

```
public static ComponentData GenerateMultiMediaComponent(TridionGeneration tridionGeneration, XmlData newsArticle, string componentName)
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> dicTridion = Common.GetTridionObject(tridionGeneration.client, ItemType.Component, tridionGeneration.Settings.ComponentFolderUri, componentName);
                int objectCount = (int)dicTridion["count"];

                SchemaFieldsData schemaFields = tridionGeneration.client.ReadSchemaFields(tridionGeneration.Settings.SchemaUri, true, new ReadOptions());




                ComponentData componentData = (ComponentData)tridionGeneration.client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, tridionGeneration.Settings.ComponentFolderUri);

                if (schemaFields.Fields != null)
                {
                    var fields = Fields.ForContentOf(schemaFields);
                    Helper.FillSchemaFields(tridionGeneration, fields);
                    componentData.Content = fields.ToString();
                }

                if (schemaFields.MetadataFields != null)
                {
                   var  metafields = Fields.ForMetadataOf(schemaFields, componentData);
                    Helper.FillSchemaFields(tridionGeneration, metafields);
                    componentData.Metadata = metafields.ToString();
                }

                componentData.Title = (objectCount == 0) ? componentName : componentName + " " + (objectCount + 1).ToString();
                componentData.ComponentType = ComponentType.Multimedia;

                StreamUpload2010Client streamClient = new StreamUpload2010Client();

                FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(@"[IMAGE_PATH]", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                string tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent("images.jpg", objfilestream);
                BinaryContentData binaryContent = new BinaryContentData();
                binaryContent.UploadFromFile = tempLocation;
                binaryContent.Filename = "[IMAGE_NAME]";
                componentData.BinaryContent = binaryContent;
                binaryContent.MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData()
                {
                    IdRef = "tcm:0-2-65544"
                };

                componentData = (ComponentData)tridionGeneration.client.Create(componentData, new ReadOptions());

                return componentData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here is the Helper class:

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static void FillSchemaFields(TridionGeneration tridionGeneration, Fields fields)
        {
            List<XmlData> data = XmlHelper.xmlData;

            var ofield = fields.GetEnumerator();
            while (ofield.MoveNext())
            {
                Field f = ofield.Current;
                FillFieldValue(tridionGeneration, fields, f, data[0]);
            }
        }

        private static void FillFieldValue(TridionGeneration tridionGeneration, Fields fields, Field f, XmlData data)
        {
            if (f.Type == typeof(MultimediaLinkFieldDefinitionData))
            {
                fields[f.Name].Value = tridionGeneration.Settings.DefaultImageUri;
            }
            else if (f.Type != typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
            {
                foreach (XmlData fieldvalue in data.Attributes)
                {
                    if (f.Type == typeof(DateFieldDefinitionData))
                    {
                        if (fieldvalue.text.ToLower() == f.Name.ToLower())
                        {
                            fields[f.Name].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(fieldvalue.value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string val = FindSchemaValue(tridionGeneration, fieldvalue.Attributes, f.Name);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                            {
                                fields[f.Name].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(val).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fieldvalue.text.ToLower() == f.Name.ToLower())
                        {
                            fields[f.Name].Value = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(fieldvalue.value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string val = FindSchemaValue(tridionGeneration, fieldvalue.Attributes, f.Name);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                            {
                                fields[f.Name].Value = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(val);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Fields fs = f.GetSubFields();
                var ofield = fs.GetEnumerator();
                while (ofield.MoveNext())
                {
                    Field ff = ofield.Current;
                    FillFieldValue(tridionGeneration, fs, ff, data);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string FindSchemaValue(TridionGeneration tridionGeneration, List<XmlData> data, string fieldname)
        {
            foreach (XmlData fieldvalue in data)
            {
                if (fieldvalue.text.ToLower() == fieldname.ToLower())
                {
                    return fieldvalue.value;
                }
                else
                {
                    FindSchemaValue(tridionGeneration, fieldvalue.Attributes, fieldname);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

and the Fields class:

```
public class Fields
    {
        private ItemFieldDefinitionData[] definitions;
        private XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager;

        private XmlElement root; // the root element under which these fields live

        // at any point EITHER data OR parent has a value
        private SchemaFieldsData data; // the schema fields data as retrieved from the core service
        private Fields parent; // the parent fields (so we're an embedded schema), where we can find the data

        public Fields(SchemaFieldsData _data, ItemFieldDefinitionData[] _definitions, string _content = null, string _rootElementName = null)
        {
            data = _data;
            definitions = _definitions;
            var content = new XmlDocument();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_content))
            {
                content.LoadXml(_content);
            }
            else
            {
                content.AppendChild(content.CreateElement(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rootElementName) ? _data.RootElementName : _rootElementName, _data.NamespaceUri));
            }
            root = content.DocumentElement;
            namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(content.NameTable);
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("custom", _data.NamespaceUri);
        }
        public Fields(Fields _parent, ItemFieldDefinitionData[] _definitions, XmlElement _root)
        {
            definitions = _definitions;
            parent = _parent;
            root = _root;
        }

        public static Fields ForContentOf(SchemaFieldsData _data)
        {
            return new Fields(_data, _data.Fields);
        }
        public static Fields ForContentOf(SchemaFieldsData _data, ComponentData _component)
        {
            return new Fields(_data, _data.Fields, _component.Content);
        }
        public static Fields ForMetadataOf(SchemaFieldsData _data, RepositoryLocalObjectData _item)
        {
            return new Fields(_data, _data.MetadataFields, _item.Metadata, "Metadata");
        }

        public string NamespaceUri
        {
            get { return data != null ? data.NamespaceUri : parent.NamespaceUri; }
        }
        public XmlNamespaceManager NamespaceManager
        {
            get { return parent != null ? parent.namespaceManager : namespaceManager; }
        }

        internal IEnumerable<XmlElement> GetFieldElements(ItemFieldDefinitionData definition)
        {
            return root.SelectNodes("custom:" + definition.Name, NamespaceManager).OfType<XmlElement>();
        }
        internal XmlElement AddFieldElement(ItemFieldDefinitionData definition)
        {
            var newElement = root.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(definition.Name, NamespaceUri);

            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("custom:" + definition.Name, NamespaceManager);
            XmlElement referenceElement = null;
            if (nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                referenceElement = (XmlElement)nodes[nodes.Count - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                // this is the first value for this field, find its position in the XML based on the field order in the schema
                bool foundUs = false;
                for (int i = definitions.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (!foundUs)
                    {
                        if (definitions[i].Name == definition.Name)
                        {
                            foundUs = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var values = GetFieldElements(definitions[i]);
                        if (values.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            referenceElement = values.Last();
                            break; // from for loop
                        }
                    }
                } // for every definition in reverse order
            } // no existing values found
            root.InsertAfter(newElement, referenceElement); // if referenceElement is null, will insert as first child
            return newElement;
        }

        public IEnumerator<Field> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<Field>)new FieldEnumerator(this, definitions);
        }
        public Field this[string _name]
        {
            get
            {
                var definition = definitions.First<ItemFieldDefinitionData>(ifdd => ifdd.Name == _name);
                if (definition == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown field '" + _name + "'");
                return new Field(this, definition);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return root.OuterXml;
        }

    }

    public class FieldEnumerator : IEnumerator<Field>
    {
        private Fields fields;
        private ItemFieldDefinitionData[] definitions;

        // Enumerators are positioned before the first element until the first MoveNext() call
        int position = -1;

        public FieldEnumerator(Fields _fields, ItemFieldDefinitionData[] _definitions)
        {
            fields = _fields;
            definitions = _definitions;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < definitions.Length);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            position = -1;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public Field Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return new Field(fields, definitions[position]);
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        private Fields fields;
        private ItemFieldDefinitionData definition;

        public Field(Fields _fields, ItemFieldDefinitionData _definition)
        {
            fields = _fields;
            definition = _definition;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return definition.Name; }
        }
        public Type Type
        {
            get { return definition.GetType(); }
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return Values.Count > 0 ? Values[0] : null;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Values.Count == 0) fields.AddFieldElement(definition);
                Values[0] = value;
            }
        }
        public ValueCollection Values
        {
            get
            {
                return new ValueCollection(fields, definition);
            }
        }

        public void AddValue(string value = null)
        {
            XmlElement newElement = fields.AddFieldElement(definition);
            if (value != null) newElement.InnerText = value;
        }

        public void RemoveValue(string value)
        {
            var elements = fields.GetFieldElements(definition);
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                if (element.InnerText == value)
                {
                    element.ParentNode.RemoveChild(element);
                }
            }
        }

        public void RemoveValue(int i)
        {
            var elements = fields.GetFieldElements(definition).ToArray();
            elements[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(elements[i]);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Fields> SubFields
        {
            get
            {
                var embeddedFieldDefinition = definition as EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData;
                if (embeddedFieldDefinition != null)
                {
                    var elements = fields.GetFieldElements(definition);
                    foreach (var element in elements)
                    {
                        yield return new Fields(fields, embeddedFieldDefinition.EmbeddedFields, (XmlElement)element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Fields GetSubFields(int i = 0)
        {
            var embeddedFieldDefinition = definition as EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData;
            if (embeddedFieldDefinition != null)
            {
                var elements = fields.GetFieldElements(definition);
                if (i == 0 && !elements.Any())
                {
                    // you can always set the first value of any field without calling AddValue, so same applies to embedded fields
                    AddValue();
                    elements = fields.GetFieldElements(definition);
                }
                return new Fields(fields, embeddedFieldDefinition.EmbeddedFields, elements.ToArray()[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You can only GetSubField on an EmbeddedSchemaField");
            }
        }
        // The subfield with the given name of this field
        public Field this[string name]
        {
            get { return GetSubFields()[name]; }
        }
        // The subfields of the given value of this field
        public Fields this[int i]
        {
            get { return GetSubFields(i); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is Fields here, is this the class written by Frank. Also could you please provide code for Helper class you have refered in code?

Comment: I don't know this class is written by frank or not but i have found this class on net. Please see the file content below.

Comment: Also please reply about FillSchemaFields() of Helper class is this your class or you had find it from net. Please provide code of Helper class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
multimediaComponent.Metadata = "<Metadata/>";
```