# How to retrieve a PDF(document) from the Tridion File System and create a multimedia component out of it

Tags: tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I am required to make changes to an existing PDF component. In doing so we are creating a new PDF in the File System with the same name as the exsting PDF and deleting the original PDF.Now the new PDF that is created after the update is required to be stored as a multimedia component.
In Tridion we generally create multimedia components to store documents in the Tridion File System. Is there a way to do the reverse , that is, retrieve a PDF(document) from the Tridion File System and create a multimedia component out of it? If so, what API'S can be used to get it done? We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 version.Please help..

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you have tried or where you have looked, but take a look at this question/answer:

[Create Multimedia component with Metadata fields.using core service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190850/create-multimedia-component-with-metadata-fields-using-core-service)

or

http://amarchuk.blogspot.com/2011/11/creating-multimedia-component-through.html